# Difference between trivially and obviously

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between **trivially** and **obviously** in a sentence like "This condition obviously/trivially holds"?

What about using them as adjectives? For example, "It is obvious/trivial that this condition holds"?

Comment: Do you actually see people use "This condition is obviously/trivially held"? Should it not be "This condition obviously/trivially holds"?

Comment: I changed it. But not sure if the previous one was correct or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider first the adjectives **trivial** and **obvious**, while they have related meanings they are not synonyms. Informally people do on occasions use the words interchangeably but they do have distinct meanings.

We can speak of **trivial** problems. Such problems have **obvious** solutions. Obvious relates to a thing we find, the etymology is of something that is "in the way", something we stumble over or just find in our path.

> How shall we get to the zoo?
>
> It's obvious, get on this bus that is labelled "London Zoo"!

In contrast, when we say

> We need to return the gorilla to the zoo. The **obvious** problem is: how do we catch him?

We are **not** saying that the problem is trivial (easy), we are saying that the problem is clear to everybody, and is probably quite difficult.

We can speak of trivial solutions and obvious solutions. The equation

[image: Fermat's last theorem]

is true for any value of **n** if a, b and c are all zero; this is a trivial solution, a solution of no interest. The interesting problem concerns the case when a, b and c are not zero.

This leads us to

> The condition is trivially held.

covers cases such as "a, b, c are all zero" above; easy to see it's correct, but of no great interest.

> The condition is obviously held

here there is some reason why the condition can be seen to be true. Sometimes a supposedly obvious solution, is only obvious once a particular insight is achieved.

> Is it obvious?
>
> Yes look ...
>
> Oh yes! Completely obvious

Comment: These are both good points. What I would highlight from the usage in mathematics is that _obvious_ and _trivial_ are informally used interchangeably/as synonyms meaning easy, but trivial has the extra meaning for cases when e.g. everything is zero and something is true but it's an uninteresting border case.

Comment: I do think that informally, away from maths, trivial tends to be used to describe problems whereas obvious more usually is applied to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any difference between the meaning of *trivially* and *obviously* as used in your first question, but trivial can also mean unimportant. You can use both as adjectives just how you suggest. Obvious is heard frequently in everyday speech, while trivially is more like scientific jargon. The Cambridge English Dictionary classifies *obvious* at the B1 level, *trivial* at the B2 level.

> **obvious**
>   adjective
>
> [B1] easy to see, recognize, or understand
>   [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obvious)
>
> **obviously**
>   adverb
>
> [B1] in a way that is easy to understand or see
>   [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obviously)
>
> **trivial**
>   adjective
>
> [B2] having little value or importance
>   A trivial problem is easy to solve
>   [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trivial)
>   [Examples for trivially](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trivially)